# React JS: React Voice to Text Recognition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, voice-recognition

I am new to React JS. I am implementing **React Voice to text** for an input box. I am using [React Voice to Text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition) plugin for my work. somehow it doesn't work for me.

Is there any other library or plugin which can be helpful to me?

I have tried the below code.

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'


const propTypes = {
  // Props injected by SpeechRecognition
  transcript: PropTypes.string,
  resetTranscript: PropTypes.func,
  browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: PropTypes.bool
}


class Dictaphone extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <span>{transcript}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


Dictaphone.propTypes = propTypes

export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone)
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: how are you using this class? it looks like you just copy/pasted that code from the npm/github instructions - where is the code that connects with a microphone or some sort of input?

Comment: Yes I have taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition . I don't know how can I connect it with my microphone or input device.?

Comment: you should do some research then, because I don't know how either and if I wanted to find out I'd do some googling

Comment: I have done research a lot. after that I posted the question on SO. the nearest solution I could find is on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition

Comment: maybe you should search for web speech api - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API - once you understand how that works, then you can see how it applies to react and this package

Comment: It works just fine. You just need to use Chrome and this library properly. It is working for me on Chrome 68 and MacOS. I am not sure how you are using it. I think that is the only issue.

Comment: @SandipNirmal  I use chrome 65.0 in my Ubuntu.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel Currently I don't have Ubuntu with me. But as per MDN it should work on Chrome 35+ on any OS. You can check it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-speech-recognition` just work fine on Chrome (Since it supports Web Speech API). I think you are not using it properly though.

Just create new React App using `create-react-app` and replace `App.js` code with following.

```
import React, {Component } from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'

class Dictaphone extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <span>{transcript}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone)
```

By default, it starts listening directly. You can control that by providing options as mentioned in the npm doc.

```
const options = {
  autoStart: false
}

export default SpeechRecognition(options)(Dictaphone)
```

Comment: @BrijeshPatel Can you just try this.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel 

Comment: just one thing. How can I change the textbox value using `onchange` method.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel I didn't get that. What exactly you want. I think you can look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition#props-added-to-your-component for all the API's available with ``react-speech-recognition``.

Comment: using this `<input type="text" value={transcript} onChange={e => this.toDoChange(e.target.value)}/>` I get the value in textbox whatever I speak. now how can I change its value. so that I can type as well as speak to get value.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel ``transcript`` is something you are getting from ``props``. You can't edit it directly. Have a ``state variable``, which you can assign to ``value=`` of input. Instead of assigning ``props`` value directly. This way you will be able to edit  it on input ``onChange``.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Dictaphone = () => {
  const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition()

  if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Dictaphone
```

for more [react speech to text demo](https://github.com/codemaker2015/react-speech-recognition-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Speechly has a great tutorial and example code for React and real time voice search. It doesn't use the Web Speech API but it's own propriety API, but configuring it is pretty simple.
Here's the tutorial for building voice search https://github.com/speechly/react-example-repo-filtering